# multiple Ip's bind on same port

Tags: networking, server, network-manager

I run multiple game servers so i added my additional ip's to the server. I made sure that the game servers ip are different but I still cant start the others server cause the ports are conflicting.

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces

# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The loading of network interface
auto em1

# The Network interfaces
iface em1 inet static

        address 173.208.251.194
        netmask 255.255.255.248
        gateway 173.208.251.193
        dns-nameservers 192.187.107.16 69.30.209.16

auto em1:2
iface em1:2 inet static

        address 173.208.251.195
        netmask 255.255.255.248

auto em1:1
iface em1:1 inet static

        address 173.208.251.197
        netmask 255.255.255.248
```

Comment: What do you mean the ports are conflicting?  For a server to start on a specific interface you normally have to "bind" it to that interface/IP.  This is all dependent on the server software really.  Any details?

Comment: @krypticgaming: it depends on the game.  You need to change the configuration file of the game daemon to run on multiple IPs.  What specific game are you talking about?

Comment: @Fabby i am running minecraft, i have changed the config file

Comment: Could you post the config files and the errors you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

When a server starts, it has to bind to which ip addresses it will listen to. Here the server specifices one or more triples of protocol (usually TCP or UDP), port number(like http or smtp) and ip address (ipv4 or ipv6).

All those are specified in the configuration files.

As long as no such triple are the same, you will have no collisio.  Except for the special address 0.0.0.0 or 0::0. These are only allowed when used as listening address, never destination address. 
They mean that the kernel (operating system) should listen on all configuted ipv4 or ipv6 addresses on the computer.  So, if you have started to listen to that address and then tries to listen to another address with same protocol and port number will conflict with previous opend ports.

So you have to find this and adjust configuration accordingly what you actually wants.

Comment: what im saying is i have a server running on xxx.xxx.xxx.xx4:25565 for expand and i want another server to run on xxx.xxx.xxx.xx5:25565 but it is saying there is a binding error

Answer (score 0):

xxx.xxx.xxx.xx4:25565 Based on what you said I am sure that you haven't used this xxx.xxx.xxx.xx4 specific IP in the server start process or server configuration. As long as you bind this port to that specific IP it can be easily used by any other IP.
For example http://www.csbestial.com is having 3 servers on differnet IPs but same Ubuntu box.
When he starts the servers he makes sure to use every IP binding in the startup process